FME Errors when opening XML
I have FME v2024 with a Floating License. I have Windows 10 Enterprise installed. I am almost out of space on my disk where my "Temp" folder is located.
The persistent problem I have with FME is that every time I try to open an XML file, although I do have the reader for it, I consistently get the same 6 errors. I have tried opening other files and there is no problem with those, only with XML files.
[1]: HTTP transfer error: Timeout was reached
[2]: Please ensure that your network connection is properly set up
[3]: No proxy settings have been entered.  If you require a proxy to access external URLs, please ensure the appropriate information has been entered.
[4]:Failed to obtain any schemas from reader 'CITYGML' from 1 datasets. This may be due to invalid datasets or format accessibility issues due to licensing, dependencies, or module loading. See logfile for more information
[5]:Workspace generation failed.  Parameter file was C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Temp\FME_1717067304960_7084.
Login failed (Connection Error) - Unable to connect to FME Flow.
[6]:Login failed (Connection Error) - Unable to connect to FME Flow.

I checked with a colleague who has the same program/license installed, and he doesn't have this issue. I have tried different solutions found on the web, checked the license, the proxy, the reader availability. I verified that the XMLs were not corrupted. None of these seemed to be the problem. I wanted to change the environmental variables of the computer, but I only have access (permission) for my user.
I already checked through the FME support webpage, but nothing could help me.
Any hints that could lead me to the source of the problem?

You have paid the license so now you have a good opportunity to get some more value for it. Contact you FME dealer.

Safe Support is quick - provide them with all the information you put in your question and submit a ticket (if you have maintenance support)  https://support.safe.com/hc/en-us/p/Support

I suspect that the reader (is it the CityGML reader?) is trying to fetch information from namespaces defined in the XML headers - for example xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" - and your computer's network settings aren't letting it.
You could try adjusting any reader settings to prevent this. For example, the XML reader has an "Ignore External DTD" parameter. You could also try having a copy of those schema documents locally. Or check with your IT team if there are any limitations that might cause this problem.
As for the FME Flow connection, I've no idea why it's trying to do that!
But as the other comments have said, if this doesn't help, please do make use of the Safe support team. That's what they're there for.
